# Log4php separate output for levelRange doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, configuration, log4php

i have a problem configuring log4php and i don't know where to check on the documentation. I have this config:

```
Logger::configure(array(
    'rootLogger' => array(
        'level' => 'INFO',
        'appenders' => array('info'),
    ),
    'loggers' => array(
        'debug' => array(
            'level' => 'DEBUG',
            'appenders' => array('debug'),
            'additivity' => false
        ),
        'error' => array(
            'level' => 'ERROR',
            'appenders' => array('error'),
            'additivity' => false
        )
    ),
    'appenders' => array(
        'info' => array(
            'class' => 'LoggerAppenderDailyFile',
            'layout' => array(
                'class' => 'LoggerLayoutPattern',
                'params' => array(
                    'conversionPattern' => '%date %logger %-5level %msg%n'
                )
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'datePattern' => 'Y-m-d',
                'file' => '../log/ilias-info-%s.log',
                'append' => true
            ),
            'filters' => array(
                    'class' => 'LoggerFilterLevelRange',
                    'params' => array(
                        'levelMin' => 'info',
                        'levelMax' => 'info',
                    )
            )
        ),
        'debug' => array(
            'class' => 'LoggerAppenderDailyFile',
            'layout' => array(
                'class' => 'LoggerLayoutPattern',
                'params' => array(
                    'conversionPattern' => '%date %logger %-5level %msg%n'
                )
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'datePattern' => 'Y-m-d',
                'file' => '../log/ilias-debug-%s.log',
                'append' => true
            ),
            'filters' => array(
                    'class' => 'LoggerFilterLevelRange',
                    'params' => array(
                        'levelMin' => 'debug',
                        'levelMax' => 'debug',
                    )
            )
        ),
        'error' => array(
            'class' => 'LoggerAppenderDailyFile',
            'layout' => array(
                'class' => 'LoggerLayoutPattern',
                'params' => array(
                    'conversionPattern' => '%date %logger %-5level %msg%n'
                )
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'datePattern' => 'Y-m-d',
                'file' => '../log/ilias-error-%s.log',
                'append' => true
            ),
            'filters' => array(
                    'class' => 'LoggerFilterLevelRange',
                    'params' => array(
                        'levelMin' => 'error',
                        'levelMax' => 'error',
                    )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Usage:
I define once the

```
$logger = Logger::getLogger(basename(__FILE__));
```

and then i log what i need like so:

```
$logger->info("INFO");
$logger->debug("DEBUG");
$logger->error("ERROR");
```

but only info's log file is created. I used the PHP way to configure the logger because for me it seems to be the easiest way to do it, but there isn't a lot of documentations about this way of doing the conf. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well, it took me awhile to get it to work too.  my current config works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
<appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderRollingFile" threshold="DEBUG">
    <layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
        <param name="conversionPattern" value="%date %-30logger %-5level %msg%n"/>
    </layout>
    <param name="file" value="/mnt/media/log/backend.debug.log"/>
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20"/>
</appender>
<appender name="splunk" class="LoggerAppenderRollingFile" threshold="INFO">
    <layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
        <param name="conversionPattern" value="%date %-30logger %-5level %msg%n"/>
    </layout>
    <param name="file" value="/mnt/media/log/backend.log"/>
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20"/>
</appender>
<appender name="console" class="LoggerAppenderConsole" threshold="DEBUG">
    <layout class="LoggerLayoutSimple">
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="TRACE"/>
    <appender_ref ref="default"/>
    <appender_ref ref="splunk"/>
    <appender_ref ref="console"/>
</root>
```

**To use this**

```
$configurator = new LoggerConfiguratorDefault();
$logConfig    = $configurator->parse(__DIR__ . "/config/log4php_backend.xml"); // this is where my xml file is located
Logger::configure($logConfig);
```

**This is the version i compose into the app**

```
"apache/log4php"          : "^2.3"
```

Comment: is there something else i could miss? However, the xml way doesn't work for me, i don't know why. Please if you can, provide a php solution.

Comment: nope for php solution. Like you, i dickered no end with that POS, so i reverted to XML, and got it working piece by piece to the above state.  I will add some kind of version of my config. Beware of my paths for the appender files : you must tailor to your own server environment.